# How to show the price $ sign and decimal in addition to $ sign with decimal

Tags: mysql

OK. I got understand if there is null data, I can put like this,

```
SELECT productName, IFNULL(price1,"" ) as First Price, IFNULL(price2, "") as Second Price from ProductP;
```

My question is, in addition to add $ sign and decimal numbers, showing as a price for only value(still null number is that I want keep blank), how to make that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there any reason you need to do that *in the SQL* as opposed to in the presentation logic of whatever is displaying this? Even the IFNULL part feels like it would be more suitable in client code.

Comment: Right. But the point of showing this way is that only there is not null value price number( such as $20.99) want to be displayed, which is more user friendly(it can be easily seen as a this is the price).

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant. My point is that you should do this at the client, so there's no point in asking for the SQL, IMO.

Comment: Well, purpose for this way is that I want see all of the result doing through test purpose using only mysql doing on this query way to show everything. Which include null value and show $ sign with decimal number.

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestion comment. But I really want to know is exact this way how to do it.

Comment: Given that that's a pretty unusual architectural decision, it would be a good idea to explain that in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you need:

```
IFNULL(concat(price1,' $'),"" )
```